# Receiving error when trying to instal Heroku packages

Tags: python, django, heroku, bootstrap-4, pip

When I am trying to install the required packages for deploying my project (Learning Log) to Heroku, it keeps giving me this error:

```
Josephs-MacBook-Pro:learning_log joseph$ source ll_env/bin/activate

(ll_env) Josephs-MacBook-Pro:learning_log joseph$ pip install psycopg2==2.7.*

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support

Collecting psycopg2==2.7.*

  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/a0/ba2c28c13bce130f971158da8fc03c231ce7778a89935eb1c3e3e6437e7c/psycopg2-2.7.7-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (1.5MB)

     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5MB 1.3MB/s 

Installing collected packages: psycopg2

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.7.7.dist-info'

Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.



(ll_env) Josephs-MacBook-Pro:learning_log joseph$ -m pip install psycopg2==2.7.*

-bash: -m: command not found
```

I don't know why it keeps saying `python 2.7` as I downloaded `python3` and have been using it the whole time.

Also when I tried running the server yesterday for Learning Log it would not work (it was running fine before). I eventually re-downloaded `python3` bootstrap4 and `django`(in the environment) and got run server to work. side note: I have to type the 3 at the end of `python3 mangage.py runserver` for it to work properly.

Any ideas how to fix this and deploy the app in Heroku?

Comment: activate the virtualenv and type: `which python`. then c/p here the result.

Comment: /usr/bin/python

Comment: Your virtualenv is using your system python. which i think it's python2.7. you can delete that virtualenv and try something like this: `virtualenv -p python3 ll_env` then activate the env and check again what python is your venv using.